# Can not find Python Quandl&Pandas Syntax Error

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, syntax-error, quandl

I was following a tutorial from this guy and I was writing the exact same code to VS code except that Quandl is not written in uppercase anymore. I will leave a ss of the code here for who don't want to watch video. [reference code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y75Vd.jpg)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lN5jesocJjk&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDfKTOs3Keq_kaG2P55YRn5v&index=3

Here is the code I wrote -exact copy of the code above but it does not work idk why:

```
import pandas as pd 
import quandl
import math
#quandl.ApiConfig.api_key  = "it is not necessary in the video but I have API key here because I signed in to Quandl site"
df = quandl.get('WIKI/GOOGL')
df = df[['Adj. Open','Adj. High','Adj. Low','Adj. Close', 'Adj. Volume']]
df["HL_PCT"] = (df["Adj. High"] - df["Adj. Close"]) / df["Adj. Close"] * 100.0
df["PCT_change"] = (df["Adj. Close"] - df["Adj. Open"]) / df["Adj. Open"] * 100.0
df = df[['Adj. Close','HL_PCT','PCT_change','Adj. Volume']]
forecast_col = 'Adj. Close'
df.fillna(-99999, inplace=True)
forecast_out = int(math.ceil(0.01*len(df)))
df['label'] = df[forecast_col].shift(-forecast_out)
df.dropna(inplace=True)
print(df.tail())
```

Here is the terminal when I tried to run : [terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKA9n.png)

ps : Code was working without any problem until I added forecast_out line, so API line does not effect the code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalid Syntax error when running python from inside Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51540391/invalid-syntax-error-when-running-python-from-inside-visual-studio-code)

Comment: @Tomerikoo nope :(

Comment: I don't know too much about Quandl, Pandas, and the terminal but it looks like you have a & there for seemingly no reason.  What happens when your remove it?

Comment: @LakshyaRaj I do not see any & in my code...

Comment: I meant in your terminal command.  I'm sorry if that's supposed to be there because I don't know much about the terminal

Comment: @LakshyaRaj yes it is supposed to be there I guess but thank you

Comment: Please don't post images of code or error messages. Please [edit] to replace the images with copy/paste of the actual text instead. Thanks. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the screenshot of the terminal you provided, the VS Code terminal is in the python interactive window. When we run the code, it executes the corresponding command in the terminal, but the python interactive window only recognizes the python code, so it displays "`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`":

[image]

Solution: Exit this python interactive window. Please type "`exit()`" or close this terminal (Kill Terminal) and reopen a new terminal.

exit:

[image]

Run:

[image]