# VS CODE - Python "RUN"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = a[:]
a[1] = 4
print(a)
print(b)
```

> **when i run this code(run python files in terminal, run selection file in terminal), i can see the two different message in terminal One
> is
>
> > > > /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3 "/Users/moontaeyeong/OneDrive/python/day 3.py"   File "", line
> > > > 1
> > > > /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3 "/Users/moontaeyeong/OneDrive/python/day 3.py"
> > > > ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax <<< and second thing is
> > > >
> > > > > printed correct value like this
> > > > > a = [1,2,3]
> > > > > b = a[:]
> > > > > a[1] = 4
> > > > > print(a) [1, 4, 3]
> > > > > print(b) [1, 2, 3]** <<<<  so.. i got a two question. first. what's the defferece between "run python files in terminal" and
> > > > > "selection python file in terminal"  second, when i run the selection
> > > > > file(whole lines), why return like that? i can't understand the reason
> > > > > why return the whole things. (what i pointed as(>>>))
> > > > > a = [1,2,3]
> > > > > b = a[:]
> > > > > a[1] = 4
> > > > > print(a)
> > > > > [1, 4, 3]
> > > > > print(b)
> > > > > [1, 2, 3] P.S. i'm not good at ENG, but i have to use this community because i heared community as the best way for strong developer, plz
> > > > > give me a hand bro :D**

Comment: Please see this lokks related. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51540391/invalid-syntax-error-when-running-python-from-inside-visual-studio-code

Comment: Yes, it's exactly that problem. For the future, please also read [ask] and take the [tour], and make sure you understand how to format your post correctly.

Comment: thank you for comment me. i'll learn how to ask and take the tour. and following the praveen's comment. i'm gonna study ENG hardly.. have a nice day!!