# Running python in terminal in vs code gives me a syntax error, however, manually selecting the code and running it does not give me the syntax error

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When I click "run python file in terminal", it gives me the following error:

```
>>> & C:/Users/HP/python/anaconda/python.exe "d:/python/vscode/python course/3. pandas/dataframes 231021.py"
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    & C:/Users/HP/python/anaconda/python.exe "d:/python/vscode/python course/3. pandas/dataframes 231021.py"
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

However, when I manually select the lines of code and press shift enter to run selected lines of code, it runs perfectly in vs code.

Comment: Can You share your code, so that I can see if there's something wrong in the code ?

Comment: It looks like you are running a shell command in the Python interpreter, which indeed would be invalid syntax.

Comment: Yes I initially thought there was something wrong with my code at first, however I tried it again with a simple code to print hello world and it gave the same error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalid Syntax error when running python from inside Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51540391/invalid-syntax-error-when-running-python-from-inside-visual-studio-code)

Comment: @GinoMempin, I have already seen that post, unfortunately its my first time using VS code so I didn't really understand the solution.

Comment: @cheesecakesss You will have to be more _specific_. If you've already seen that post, then please [edit] your question to describe which of those answers you've already checked/tried, what happened, and what specifically you didn't understand about those answers.

Comment: The answer on the post said to use the exit() command in the console. I don't understand  what console this is.

Comment: The one where your syntax error is appearing. The one with the `>>>`. It's called the python shell or python console. See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html#interactive-mode. The answer means to hit the enter key until you get a blank `>>>` prompt, then type in `exit()`.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the terminal and on the right side you will see a docked panel named powershell
and when you hover over it it will show a dustbin ui(image like a dustbin). If you have multiple tabs close everything by clicking on the dustbin. Doing this, the terminal will close then simply run the code again and the problem should be solved!(It worked for me after fiddling for 3 days)

Note: Everything should be closed on the terminal right side panel. If the terminal doesn't closes, try closing vs code and open again and do the same thing. Mine had python opened too in the docked panel.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you didn't exit python first. Python is giving you the syntax error, not the shell.

Just type in `quit()` into the terminal window, then re-run and it will work fine.

I had the same problem before I realized that shift-Return to run certain lines uses the open interpreter, but run file assumes you are starting at a shell prompt.

Answer (score -1):

I will suggest check the python version both on the command prompt and within the VS Code. I suspect they point to different versions. In this case you create virtual environment using venv and share the same in both cases so that you will get consistent output.