# cannot obtain output in VS code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

i am not getting any output whenever i try to execute any basic command , in python using VS code.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalid Syntax error when running python from inside Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51540391/invalid-syntax-error-when-running-python-from-inside-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Visual Studio Terminal has Python already opened, so when you try to execute the:
`& "C:/python 39/python.exe" "C:/route_to_your_file.py"`
Is trying to execute a line of code with this, something that has a bad python syntax.

You have two options:

1. Close python writing `exit()` and then run your python script with `"C:/python 39/python.exe" main2.py` or `"C:/python 39/python.exe" main3.py`
2. Work directly with the application of python. In that case you can write your code directly on the terminal

```python3
print("hello world")
```

you can (but it is not recommended) import your files as packages, with:

```python
import main2
import main3
```

Since you are new on python, I recommend you the first option.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to run python while already in python. Try opening a bash or cmd terminal and typing in `python main3.py`

Answer (score 0):

Run the code directly:

[image]

rather than get into python then run the code:

[image]

Comment: @Adwet Anurag Dash Have you solved the problem? if this is helpful, could you accept this answer? thanks, and have a good day : )